# How to create grid with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4, what is the difference between the sections "test 1" and "test 2"?  Im trying to create a layout that puts a modest gutter between the columns. One has  elements within the row and the other does not

```
 <style type="text/css">
.section
{
    font-family:Arial;      
    border-color: #0080ff;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:10px; 
    background-color:#99ff99;   
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 Box model:<br/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>test 1</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 section">left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 section">right</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>test 2</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="section">.col-sm-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><div class="section">.col-sm-8</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output
[image]

The end goal:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gutter" (spacing between columns is created with padding). To change it, adjust the padding...

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 px-2"><div class="section">.col-sm-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 px-2"><div class="section">.col-sm-8</div></div>
  </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/FlMQ4xVRbs